# open Window store App in Window Phone in javascript or php

Tags: javascript, php, windows

i need to send message containing Single url for installing app . User click on url then based on user's device window / Mac/ google 's store will be open

Following code redirect to Google Play Store, Mac App Store. but it do not redirect to window Store.

switch (_getOS())
{
    case "Mac":
        header("location:https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/one-touch-response/id987064767?mt=8");
    break;

`case "Android":
         header("location:https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.luckey.onetouch1&hl=en");
    break;

    default:
         header("location:http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=b9d594c5-6b7e-4b25-86cb-068f55a1f7bb");
    break;`

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are trying to get Operating system type type from HTTP USER AGENT

Some times it returns us wrong string and combination of multiple OS names Please recheck the string of HTTP user agent and try again

It may work for you..

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn770213%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

Just add your app ID to the end of this URL:

```
 ms-windows-store:navigate?appid=[your app ID]
```

For future reference, you can also search the app store with this URI scheme:

```
 ms-windows-store:search?publisher=[your publisher display name]
```